# Java: Moving percentage sign, or padding with spaces after the percentage sign

Tags: java, printf, percentage, decimalformat

I need to my output to match the following (I'm mainly concerned with the percentage value):

```
100% | 03 games
75%  | 04 games
14%  | 07 games
```

I'm having trouble getting them to line up beneath one another. The first integer needs to be left-justified. I tried using `printf("%-3d%%", percentage)` - they line up fine, but there is a gap between the first integer and the percentage sign (when its not equal to 100):

```
100% | 03 games
75 % | 04 games
14 % | 07 games
```

I also tried a DecimalFormat specifier, `"##0%"`, but the problem is then that percentage values with different numbers of digits don't line up - there is always only one space between `%` and `|`, when there sometimes needs to be two or three.

```
100% | 03 games
75% | 04 games
14% | 07 games
```

How might I resolve this? Is there a way to pad with spaces after the percentage sign? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change font of console to consolas or courier if it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String.format twice:

```
String inner = format("%d%%", yourNumber); // creates "42%"
String outer = format("%-4s", inner); // creates "42% "
```